# Bad access when closure completes

Tags: rust

I'm currently calling a native function from my Rust application. The function takes a callback which takes a `const char*` string.

I'm using a trampoline function to pass in as the native callback. I'm then passing in the closure `error_handler` as an opaque pointer (`user_data`). The trampoline function, when called by the native library, casts the opaque pointer to the closure type, and invokes it with the `C` string.

In the code below, if I just print the value of the `C` string passed to the closure (`error_handler`) everything works fine.

If, however, I capture the `error` variable in the closure, when the closure scope ends a `EXC_BAD ACCESS` exception is thrown. Execution of the application stops at the library function `pub unsafe fn drop_in_place<T: ?Sized>(to_drop: *mut T)`

I'm wondering if the `error_handler` closure is attempting to drop the `error` reference it has which is causing it to blow up but I'm really unsure.

So, where I'm at right now, I can successfully print the value of the `C` string but I'm unable to capture that value in the outer scope (which is the entire reason why I'm using the trampoline function.

Also, although this is not the question being asked, if someone has a better solution I'd really like to hear it.

#### Rust

```
impl MyStruct {
    
    pub fn start( &self ) {
    
        let mut error: Option<String> = None;

        // Closure is invoked from trampoline function.
        let mut error_handler = | errors: *const c_char | {        
            let c_str = unsafe { CStr::from_ptr( errors ) };
        
            if let Ok( s ) = c_str.to_str( ).map( | s | s.to_owned( ) ) {
                error = Some( s );
            }
        }; // <-- When the scope of the closure ends a BAD_ACCESS exception is thrown.

        let trampoline = get_trampoline( &mut error_handler );

        unsafe {
            native_func( trampoline, &mut error_handler as *mut _ as *mut c_void );
        }

        if let Some( e ) = error { // Do something with error. }
    }
}

type ErrorCallback = unsafe extern "C" fn( *const c_char, *mut c_void );

unsafe extern "C" fn trampoline<F>( error: *const c_char, user_data: *mut c_void)
where
    F: FnMut( *const c_char ),
{
    // Cast the user data to the closure passed in above.
    let user_data = &mut *( user_data as *mut F );
    user_data( error );
}

// Rust's version of decltype...
fn get_trampoline<F>( _ : F ) -> ErrorCallback
where 
    F: FnMut( *const c_char ) 
{
    trampoline::<F>
}

#[link( name = "mylib" )]
extern { 
    fn native_func( error: ErrorCallback,
                    user_data: *mut c_void );
}
```

#### C++

```
extern "C" 
void native_func( ErrorCallback error,
                  void* user_data )
{
    try 
    {
        // Call a function that intentionally throws to test the
        // error callback.
    }
    catch( const std::exception& ex )
    { 
        if ( error ) 
        {
            std::string e{ ex.what( ) };
            error( e.data( ), user_data ); 
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: https://rust.godbolt.org/z/j6rYG7

Comment: :O Wow, I was just doing that so it would show the assembly! Strange... Also, are you able to use [Miri](https://github.com/rust-lang/miri), and does it have any useful info? BTW, here's the MIR generated, which should show when drops occur: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7b4a757db3a4ae3f5e5385ff3f9ae168 (change Build to MIR)

Comment: @SolomonUcko I was wrong. I deleted my comment. I'm still getting `exception` even when using a `free` function instead. And no, I'm not using `Miri` I had never heard of it until now.

Comment: I feel like it has something to do with `allocating`/`deallocating` the `std::String` in the context of the `native` application.

Comment: BTW, I think I have reproduced the crash without FFI: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=32bc64ffb40a318816906350cc3eff0f

Comment: It looks like Miri found a null pointer dereference, or something? Try running https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=32bc64ffb40a318816906350cc3eff0f with Tools > Miri.

Comment: @SolomonUcko First of all the playground with `Miri` is amazing. Anyway, it's interesting that it's initially pointing out `error = Some( s );` `inbounds test failed: 0x0 is not a valid pointer`. It looks like the captured `error` variable is `null`

Comment: Hmm... Is `user_data` somehow getting zeroed? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f944f738de9ff83a3bd1d9fb6e08b2f9

Comment: @SolomonUcko I don't think so, if I don't capture any variables in the `closure` everything works as expected. Even if I do capture I can see that the `closure` does get called successfully (it just crashes when it attempts to assign a value to the captured variable)

Comment: @SolomonUcko I ran it to the exact same issue... The captured variable is always null.. Maybe Ill just re-write the native function to take an `**error` out variable. That way I can bypass this issue

Comment: @SolomonUcko So if I use a `mutable global` variable it works. So it appears I have a lifetime problem.

Comment: The strangest thing for now is that it does not segfault if `error` is initialized with `Some("non-empty string")`  https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=32422c4f661afdaacd0affef93edd7b8 (with `Some("")` error persists). Looks like some miscompilation for me. (upd: in Release mode, `Some("error")` segfaults too)

Comment: @WBuck it's not a lifetime problem it's a calling conventions problem: fn() is a function pointer but a closure *is not a function*, it's closer to a struct witn an associated function. I'm surprised it even manages to call the function, but when it does the implicit environment is unlikely to correctly be set.

Comment: Rather than attempting to have `user_data` be a closure, why don't you make it a struct and the error callback a static function which stores crap into that struct?

Comment: @Masklinn So I went the struct route and it worked as excepted. The struct solution is a bit easier to reason about as well.